# Can the installation of Oracle APEX on LINUX be accomplished if Oracle DB resides on separate system?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Wonder if this can be achieved. Install Oracle APEX onto a Linux VM and have Oracle DB residing on a separate server to point to it. Is it possible to install Oracle APEX without Oracle currently installed on the same box? Can't find any documentation on the Oracle site for this setup.

Comment: Most of the APEX functionality is within the Oracle database, and that's a requirement. You can't remove APEX from Oracle, all you can do it host the images and other OS level files on another server. For example, we have APEX installed in an Oracle database, which is a requirement, but then we have the images on a different server and access it through Tomcat (Oracle REST Data Services) / Apache. There's no way to run APEX without an Oracle database. https://apex.oracle.com/en/platform/architecture/

Comment: okay. Thank you for your help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Application Express (APEX) runs out of the database itself. APEX is a collection of PL/SQL packages and tables.

Now the web tier could most definitely be moved to another machine (linux even). That would be something like Oracle REST Data Services and Apache Tomcat.

Comment: thank you as well. This should be enough to get me started.